# SequelizeConnectionError: The server does not support SSL connections

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, ssl, sequelize.js

I am trying to connect my project with PostgreSQL but show this error. Please help me
I have installed Postgres.app and for GUI PgAdmin.

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: The server does not support SSL connections
        at /Users/inamur/Documents/Project/project-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:186:20
        at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/Users/inamur/Documents/Project/project-api/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:203:14)
        at Connection.emit (events.js:223:5)
        at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/inamur/Documents/Project/project-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:90:21)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
        at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
        at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
        at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:23)
```

This is my .env file

```
JWT_SECRET='UserNews'
DB_LINK='postgres://root:root@localhost:5432/SCROLL001?ssl=true'
```

This is connection file.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_LINK, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  protocol: 'postgres',
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      require: 'true'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Does your DB require SSL connections>

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth Yes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_LINK, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  protocol: 'postgres',
  dialectOptions: {}, //removed ssl
});
```

Change the DB Link

```
DB_LINK='postgres://root:root@localhost:5432/SCROLL001'
```

Comment: Can someone please specify what's the difference btw ssl: false and giving it like this mentioned here { } - empty object :)

Comment: I would also like to know the answer here to @AshutoshTiwari 's question. Why is it necessary to pass an empty object to dialectOptions rather than specifying false?

Answer (score 5):

It is recommended to use SSL for connections in production applications. You can continue to use an SSL connection using while circumventing it locally using:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_LINK, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  protocol: 'postgres',
  ssl: process.env.DB_ENABLE_SSL,
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: process.env.DB_ENABLE_SSL && {
      require: true
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven`t used dialectOptions correctly.

Just make the following changes:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_LINK, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  protocol: 'postgres',
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: true,
    native:true
  }
});
```

native flag for using a native library or not.In the case of 'pg' -- set this to true will allow SSL support, default value is false. [reference link](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/sequelize/sequelize/manual/usage.html)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by setting ssl to true in the `dialectoptions` as follows:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_LINK,
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        dialectoptions: {
            ssl: true
        }
    }
)
```

And then appended `?sslmode=require` at the end of the `DB_LINK` string as follows:
`postgres://root:root@localhost:5432/SCROLL001?sslmode=require`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by setting `rejectUnauthorized` to `false`, but I would not use this in production code:

```js
dialectOptions: {
  supportBigNumbers: true,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false, // Trust the self-signed certificate
  }
}
```

Complete code:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_LINK, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  protocol: 'postgres',
  dialectOptions: {
    supportBigNumbers: true,
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false, // Trust the self-signed certificate
    }
  }
});
```